# Why is the generator infinite?

Tags: python, generator, infinite-loop

Please take a look at this generator of generators (written in Python):

```
def gen_chars():
    def gen_row(j):
        while True: yield from j

    for l in ['1234', 'abc', 'ABC', '0']: yield gen_row(l)
```

What I don't understand is:

Why any of these four generators is infinite?

For example: Why the first generator is: 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, ... (the loop never ends),

and not just: 1, 2, 3, 4 (end)?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: The `while` loop is the only part of this that makes it infinite. `while True` with no way to exit the loop will continue yeilding from j (the list that is input to `gen_row` infintely.

Comment: Remember that `j` in your inner loop is a string, not a generator.  `yield from` asks it to behave as a generator, but the rules are different.

Comment: @TimRoberts why do you say the rules are different? They're not really different at all?

Comment: Sort of.  If `j` were a generator, then after the first time through the while loop, the generator would be exhausted.  Game over.  No automatic rewind.  With a string, every time it does another while loop, the string starts over.

Answer (score 2):

it loops infinitely because you have a `while True` in your `gen_row` and no condition to exit it. so this will loop and yield forever from `j`, in this case `'1234'`, because it was the first time ever, this function was called.

Answer (score 1):

`while True` will always cause an infinite loop unless you break out of it at some point. If you are trying to yield each individual character from each item in the list then you should do something like this:

```
def gen_chars():
   def gen_row(j):
      for c in j:
         yield c

   for l in ['1234', 'abc', 'ABC', '0']: yield gen_row(l)
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider this simpler example:

```
def g():
    yield from '1234'


def h():
    while True:
        yield from '1234'


for x in g():
    print(x)

for x in h():
    print(x)
```

What do you expect to happen during the first for loop? It appears, from your question, that you might expect it to yield `'1234'` in one go. Or perhaps you expect what actually happens, it yields `'1'`, `'2'`, etc.

`yield from` some iterable yields one value at a time.

If that makes sense, it should also make sense that the generator `h()` will yield the same characters one at a time, but once that's done, the `while True:` will cause it do that again and again, forever.

This is what happens in the first generator yielded by your generator generator and since that's the first generator you start drawing from, you're stuck getting values from it forever.